# Image size of 256x256 (not 299x299) fed into Inception v3 model (PyTorch) and works?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am testing out the pretrained inception v3 model on Pytorch. I fed it an image size 256x256 and also resized it up to 299x299. In both cases, the image was classified correctly.

Can someone explain why the PyTorch pretrained model can accept an image that's not 299x299?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the pytorch implementation of inception v3 uses an adaptive average pooling layer right before the fully-connected layer.

If you take a look at the `Inception3` class in `torchvision/models/inception.py`, the operation of most interest with respect to your question is `x = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(x, (1, 1))`. Since the [average pooling is adaptive](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d) the height and width of `x` before pooling are independent of the output shape. In other words, after this operation we always get a tensor of size `[b,c,1,1]` where `b` and `c` are the batch size and number of channels respectively. This way the input to the fully connected layer is always the same size so no exceptions are raised.

That said, if you're using the pretrained inception v3 weights then the model was originally trained for input of size 299x299. Using inputs of different sizes may have a negative impact on loss/accuracy, although smaller input images will almost certainly decrease computational time and memory footprint since the feature maps will be smaller.

Comment: One thing to add. When you're reducing or increasing the resolution, one should pay attention to the padding/striding behaviour of the network from input to pre-pool feature map. It's best to change the input res in steps that result in an increase or decrease in the final feature map dimension that does not alter the alignment of the feature maps through the network. For Inception, moving in 32 pixel amounts from 299 works best. So, 331, 299, 267, 235 will give you reasonable results. 235 gives you better results than 256.

Comment: @rwightman: Could you explain how you compute that 32 pixels works best? Why does that not alter the alignment and what does it mean to 'alter the alignment'? Thanks

Comment: @Niklas When you perform strided convolution or pooling you should make sure that the shape of the input feature map is such that all the input features are considered. For example if you had an input shape of size 4 and a kernel of size 3, stride of 2, and no padding then the convolution/pooling operation will necessarily not consider one of the elements in the input signal. Instead, if the input shape were 3 or 5 then all the input features would be used. This is what is meant by an "alignment" issue.

Answer (score 5):

Inception-v3 will work with `size >= 299 x 299` during training when `aux_logits` is True, otherwise it can work with size as small as `75 x 75`.

The reason is when `aux_logits` is set True during training, it internally calls [`InceptionAux`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/inception.html#inception_v3) after Mixed_6e layer, which contains 2D convolution with kernel of `5 x 5`. Now if input image is smaller than `299 x 299`, it so happens that output size of Mixed_6e is actually smaller than kernel size `5 x 5` in `InceptionAux`. Hence image size must be >= `299 x 299` during training if `aux_logits` is set to be True.

Otherwise, if `aux_logits` is False, we can use smaller input sizes (`256 x 256` in your case), as model will not call `IncpetionAux`, hence no `5 x 5` kernel size convolution.

During testing (`model.training = False`), `InceptionAux` is not called even if `aux_logits` is True. Therefore, one can easily use smaller sizes as input. I have tested and it works until `75 x 75`.

Comment: model.aux_logits = False did not work for me, but model.AuxLogits = None did.